# highcharts dataLabel overflow: justify issue

Tags: highcharts

I've upgraded from highcharts 3.0.5 to 3.0.7 and with that change came the dataLabels `overflow:justify` property that is set to justify the dataLabels (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WN8wV/) for an example). This will just slide labels that fall outside of the chart into the bar, but the color doesn't change and there doesn't appear to be an option to change the color. Is there A) any way to force the label to appear beside the bar and readjust the size of the bars, or B) any way to change the color when `overflow: justify` kicks into play?

The only "fix" that immediately comes to mind is to provide some maxPadding, but that feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead you can use the property

```
overflow: 'none',
crop: false
```

here is the API [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.overflow)

I hope this will help you

Comment: Right, when you do this, the labels can expand beyond the border of the table though. My current solution is to just let the chart justify, then provide a backgroundColor for the label. I may put a border on the background to make it more visible, but haven't done so.

Comment: The best and simplest answer, but the attributes are flipped. They should be `overflow: 'none', crop: false`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same thing and came up with a solution that appears to work for my scenario.

After rendering the chart, I look through the series for dataLabels that have been right-aligned, then change them to white using jQuery.

```
// snipped: rendering the chart


var chart = $('#chartContainer').highcharts(),   
    labels = $('#chartContainer').find(".highcharts-data-labels tspan"),
    indexesNeedingWhite = [];

$.each(chart.series[0].data, function (index, data) {
    if (data.dataLabel.alignOptions.align === "right") {
        indexesNeedingWhite.push(index);
    }
});

// find the exact text label within this container
// and change the fill to white
$.each(indexesNeedingWhite, function (i, index) {
    $(labels[index]).css('fill', 'white');
});
```